# void loop is only run once why?it can recive only off signal?

Tags: arduino-uno, home-automation

[image: circuit][image: bluetooth app]    int L1=12;

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(L1,OUTPUT); 

}

void loop() {

char receive=Serial.read();

if(Serial.available()>0){
    receive = Serial.read();
}

{

if(receive =='A') { 
  digitalWrite(L1,HIGH);
} 

if(receive =='a') { 
  digitalWrite(L1,LOW);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int L1=12;



void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(L1,OUTPUT); 

}

void loop() {

//char receive=Serial.read(); //This is incorrect. because after u perform this serial.read(), the received data in serial's buffer is cleared. So ...

if(Serial.available()>0){
    receive = Serial.read(); //... at here, your 'receive' receives nothing
}

{

if(receive =='A') { 
  digitalWrite(L1,HIGH);
} 

if(receive =='a') { 
  digitalWrite(L1,LOW);
}
}
}
```

Here's the correct codes.

```
int L1=12;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(L1,OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() 
{
  char receive;

  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    receive = Serial.read();

    if(receive =='A') 
    { 
      digitalWrite(L1,HIGH);
    } 

    else if(receive =='a') 
    { 
      digitalWrite(L1,LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nice, but not solving. if he sends only one character, this changes do not change the behavior of the sketch. read returns -1 if nothing is available. if the first read returns the character then next character is not available and the received character is compared to 'A' and 'a'.

Comment: so what should i do so that every time i send a character it receive and execute the conditions

Comment: @JhonRajbongshi, the problem is not in sketch